# Ruby function to get specific item in array and dynamically get nested data

Tags: ruby, middleman

If I have an array of hashes that looks like this

```
array = [{
  name: 'Stan',
  surname: 'Smith',
  address: {
    street: 'Some street',
    postcode: '98877',
    #...
  }
}, {
  #...
}]
```

can you write a function to get a specific item in an array, iterate over it and dynamically retrieve subsequently nested data?

This example doesn't work, but hopefully better explains my question:

```
def getDataFromFirstItem(someVal)
  array(0).each{ |k, v| v["#{ someVal }"] }
end

puts getDataFromFirstItem('name')
# Expected output: 'Stan'
```

For context, I'm trying to create a Middleman helper so that I don't have to loop through a specific array that only has one item each time I use it in my template. The item (a hash) contains a load of global site variables. The data is coming from Contentful, within which everything is an array of entries.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you give a complete example of the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for responding... I've added the expected output. Does that help? Let me know if you need more.

Comment: So does `array[0][:name]` do what you want?

Comment: As @pascalbetz suggests.  If you're passing the key as a string, you might want to do `def getDataFromFirstItem(someVal); array.first[someVal.to_sym];end`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that does work for this example, but it seems not with Middleman's data, which contains some 'enhanced' hash thing (`#<Middleman::Util::EnhancedHash item_one=...`), which isn't allowing me to do this... Anyway, this is clearly beyond me and the scope of the original question, so I'll mark yours correct if you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
array = [{
  name: 'Stan',
  surname: 'Smith',
  address: {
    street: 'Some street',
    postcode: '98877',
    #...
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Nimish',
    surname: 'Gupta',
    address: {
      street: 'Some street',
      postcode: '98877',
      #...
    }
  }
]


def getDataFromFirstItem(array, someVal)
  array[0][someVal]
end

#Run this command
getDataFromFirstItem(array, :name) # => 'Stan'

#Please notice I send name as a symbol instead of string because the hash you declared consists of symbol keys

#Also if you want to make a dynamic program that works on all indexes of an array and not on a specific index then you can try this

def getDataFromItem(array, index, someVal)
  if array[index]
    array[index][someVal]
  end
end

getDataFromItem(array, 0, :name) # => Stan
getDataFromItem(array, 1, :name) # => Nimish
getDataFromItem(array, 2, :name) # => nil
```

Hope this works, Please let me know if you still faces any issues

Answer (score 2):

Starting in ruby 2.3 and greater, you can use [`Array#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-dig) and [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) which both

> Extracts the nested value specified by the sequence of *idx* objects by calling dig at each step, returning `nil` if any intermediate step is `nil`.

```
array = [{
  name: 'Stan',
  surname: 'Smith',
  address: {
    street: 'Some Street',
    postcode: '98877'
  }
}, {
}]

array.dig(0, :name)               # => "Stan"
array.dig(0, :address, :postcode) # => "98877"
array.dig(0, :address, :city)     # => nil
array.dig(1, :address, :postcode) # => nil
array.dig(2, :address, :postcode) # => nil
```